# Managing git branches

Tags: git

I'm looking for some advice on how I can achieve the following using Git:

Branches:
master (stable branch)
unstable

All work is done in unstable branch, in which the code might not work at any point, but I push to it to save my progress.  When I reach a stable point, I want to make master exactly the same as unstable.  I don't want to have to go through all my changes when merging and select the unstable branch state, I just want it to use the unstable branch state and make master exactly the same.  It might need to delete some files, add some files, change some files. I don't want to copy all the commits from unstable to master, but just add one new commit with all the changes.

The only two ways I've seen to do this successfully are

```
git checkout master
git reset --hard unstable
```

but this seems to copy all the commits in unstable and then I can't push master to remote (rejected by remote)
or

```
git checkout master
rm -rf ./*
```

Then copy all files from the other branch and commit.

There must be a better way to do this, or maybe a completely different approach?

Comment: take a look at [git flow](http://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/), it's very interesting

Answer (score 4):

```
git checkout master
git merge --squash unstable
git commit
```

Will make a single commit with all the changes (commits in the unstable branch) made since your last merge.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like `master` doesn't change while you are developing in `unstable`.  You have two options, depending on how you want the final tree to look.

Say you start with this tree:

```
A---B         (master)
     \
      C---D   (unstable)
```

If you want `master` to simply fast-forward to `unstable` (a single trunk, `master` and `unstable` point to the same commit):

```
git checkout master
git rebase unstable
```

Resulting tree:

```
A---B---C---D  (master, unstable)
```

If you want a merge commit (`unstable` branches off, then merges back into `master`):

```
git checkout master
git merge --no-ff unstable
```

Resulting tree:

```
A---B-------D'  (master)
     \     /
      C---D     (unstable)
```

**Update** As @KurzedMetal was kind enough to point out, you don't want either of these options.  His answer is correct, I think.  The tree after `git merge --squash unstable master; git commit` would look like:

```
A---B---------E  (master)
     \
      C---D      (unstable)
```

Note the lack of a relationship between `master` and `unstable`.  After this, you might want to reset `unstable` with:

```
git checkout unstable
git reset --hard master
```

Resulting in:

```
A---B---E       (master, unstable)
```

I'm not sure why you would want to use this strategy, though.  Losing all that history seems unwise to me.

Comment: I think he doesn't want any of these results: "I don't want to copy all the commits from unstable to master, but just add one new commit with all the changes" He wants one commit with all the changes, that's what squash do. Good info tho +1

Answer (score 0):

`git checkout master`

`git merge unstable`

then you will have a merge commit, and your state in master will be exactly the same with unstable branch.

Once you think your merge is break, and you can just fallback one commit (the merge commit), and will back to original state. kid stuff :)